# github api Name of the user is different in Search info results and User complete info results, how can i get correct name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, github-api

I am using github_api gem in my rails application.

NOTE: check the name of the user, in first result name is "koti" , in second result "Koteswara Rao".

My question is how can i get Original user info name in search result

I am searching a user by the 
" github.search.users keyword:'koti' ", 
it gives follwing results

id: user-419173

username: koti

login: koti

name: koti

location: Hyderabad

fullname: koti

Now i am fetch complete profile by
github.users.get user:'koti'
it gives follwing results

https://api.github.com/users/koti

login: "koti",

id: 419173,

type: "User",

name: "Koteswara Rao",

location: "Hyderabad",

NOTE: check the name of the user, in first result name is "koti" , in second result "Koteswara Rao".

My question is how can i get Original user info name in search result

thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the actual response from the API:

```
 {'created': '2010-09-28T13:18:51Z',
  'created_at': '2010-09-28T13:18:51Z',
  'followers': 0,
  'followers_count': 0,
  'fullname': 'koti',
  'gravatar_id': 'f0c61bf644dd80528d657c702f3b1b63',
  'id': 'user-419173',
  'language': 'Java',
  'location': 'Hyderabad',
  'login': 'koti',
  'name': 'koti',
  'public_repo_count': 1,
  'repos': 1,
  'score': 15.631338,
  'type': 'user',
  'username': 'koti'}
```

That is every single field returned by GitHub. In other words, there is no way to get `Koteswara Rao` from the search API. This could be a bug in the API so you're more than welcome to [contact GitHub](https://github.com/contact) directly about it. If you do contact them, please put "API" in the subject line to reduce the response time to your support request.

Comment: @RanjithReddy the only way to get the full name of any use is exactly the way you're doing it. You asked how to do it via the Search API and as I demonstrated, that's not possible.